# How to scale my ball as a child of another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]I have a ball as a child of a bowl that will be shot like a slingshot. But when I shoot my ball, my ball looks oval or egg shape. Im trying to scale it to look better like a ball. Any advice how to fix this? I want the ball to still be a child of the bowl tho.

Comment: The easiest way would be ... don't make the ball a child. If this is about physics then rather use a proper [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Bowl <-scaled
  - ball
```

Where ball inherits the scale of the Bowl do this:

```
Parent
   - bowl <- scaled
   - ball
```

If you say "but I want the ball to be the child of bowl then I say this:

```
Bowl
   - bowl mesh <- scaled
   - ball
```

Comment: should i make a new empty child and add the bowl mesh with scare or make a new empty parent named bowl and add my old bowl as a child?

Comment: im just a confused, should i make a parent name bawl and add its components it needs and then second make it a child and make a mesh and the scale i want?

Comment: the whole idea is to not not inherit the scale of your bowl mesh. So make the bowl mesh a child of a new parent so that ball can be a child of that parent and not inherit the scale. It's up to you where you put the components. Try it. See what works. Why are you are afraid to experiment? Get an idea, get a part of an idea and run with it. Get another idea and run with that too. Then get another idea and run with it. Don't just stare at your editor wondering if that works or if that works, implement that and that and see if it works.

Comment: thats what ive been doing this whole time, experimenting with my own ideas lol just wanted to know if people had better ideas to be helpful. But besides that your way dont work unfortunate :/ thanks tho

Comment: There is no reason why this wouldn't work. Anyway there's too little information to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating the ball, don't instantiate it as the child of the bawl. Instead, instantiate it first in world space, then assign the bawl as a parent. This will prevent scaling issues.

Comment: not if you scale the bowl afterwards ....